# Android - Jsoup login to website

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Could anyone explain how to log in to this http://ecampus.smu.ac.kr/ website using JSoup?

My code currently (Completely fails, I'm sure I'm on the wrong 'track'):

```
 class Insert extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://ecampus.smu.ac.kr/login/index.php")
                    .data("username", "201490008", "password", "*******")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();
            Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ecampus.smu.ac.kr/").cookies(loginCookies).get();
            Elements elements = doc.select(".course_name");
            arrayList.clear();
            for (Element element : elements) {
                arrayList.add(element.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How do you know the site accepts POST requests at all?

Comment: I don't know I think yes @cricket_007

Comment: this link is our univecity's link and I want to connect my app to this link. 2 days ago this code was worked but today it is not working. @cricket_007

Comment: It does indeed accept POST requests, but it also has an additional parameter named `rememberusername` for the small checkbox that needs to be considered

Comment: ...and most probably you will also have to set additional headers for your request (like `http://ecampus.smu.ac.kr/` as `Referer` etc.)

Comment: how to do it. I just really have no idea about the POST.
you can show an example @devnull69

Comment: and it get me this error  (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this to send POST requests via Jsoup and retrieve a document

First: Set up a cookie manager to handle all your cookie stuff

```
CookieManager cm = new CookieManager();
CookieManager.setDefault(cm);
```

Second: Create a `Map<String, String>` for your POST parameters

```
HashMap<String, String> postMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
postMap.put("username", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
postMap.put("password", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
postMap.put("rememberusername", "on");
```

Finally: Set specific headers (in my example the referer and the userAgent) to execute the POST request

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36";
String referer = "http://ecampus.smu.ac.kr/";
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://ecampus.smu.ac.kr/login/index.php")
        .data(postMap)
        .userAgent(userAgent)
        .referrer(referer)
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .execute();

Document doc = res.parse();
```

The userAgent will make the server think that it's not a mobile device. This should work.